# How to use default modifier with a list of values in a impex - hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I wrote an impex that look like this:

```
UPDATE B2BCustomer; uid[unique=true];groups(uid)[mode=remove][default=group1, group2, group3]
;00003269;
```

In my example, the b2bCustomer 00003269 has only one of these 3 groups (the group3). The impex is executing without error, but it's not removing the group3 from the customer.

If I move the value from the default modifier to the row, it works:

```
UPDATE B2BCustomer; uid[unique=true];groups(uid)[mode=remove]
;00003269;group1, group2, group3
```

What should I do to make my first example work as expected?

Comment: In your ImpEx, the default is `group1` i.e. if the user has `group1` and you do not provide values for `groups`, the system will remove `group1`.

You can try either of the following: `UPDATE B2BCustomer; uid[unique=true];groups(uid)[mode=remove][default=group3, group1, group2]
    ;00003269;` ---or--- `UPDATE B2BCustomer; uid[unique=true];groups(uid)[mode=remove][default=group1, group2, group3]
    ;00003269;group3`

Comment: I am trying to update a huge list, some of them will have all the 3 groups, some of them will have 2, some will have only1. So it needs to work in no particular order. It works fine if the 3 values are in the row. It only doesn't work if they are in the default value header.

Comment: I just notice the default value is not working with remove mode even if it's only one value instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `mode=remove` and `default` will work at the same time. `default` takes effect when there is no value in the data line.

If B2BCustomer has group1, group2, and group3, and you want to remove group3, do:

> UPDATE B2BCustomer;uid[unique=true];groups(uid)[mode=remove]
> ;00003269;group3

Also, if you have multiple default values, you should group them with a single quote.

> UPDATE B2BCustomer;uid[unique=true];groups(uid)[default='group1,group2,group3']
> ;00003269;